# pass a variable from a radio button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

I am attempting to pass the variable from a radio button to a variable in a javascript link. I am not able to get the variable 'testVar', which is in the for loop checking for the checked radio button, passed to the  link. I am stumped and this is the complete code:

```
 <form>
    <label>Priority 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="priority" name="priorityN" onclick="getResults();" value="prior1"  />
    <label>Priority 2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="priority" name="priorityN" onclick="getResults();" value="prior2"  />
</form>

<br /><br />

<div id="myLink"></div>

<script>

var testVar = '';

function getResults() {
var radios = document.getElementsByName("priorityN");

for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {       
    if (radios[i].checked) {
        testVar = (radios[i].value);
    //  alert(radios[i].value);
        break;
    }
}
}

document.getElementById("myLink").innerHTML = '<a href=\"' + 'www.example.com?pri=' + testVar + '\" onclick=\"$(this).modal({width:880, height:460}).open(); return false;\" >' + 'My Modal Link' + "</a>";

</script>
```

Comment: If you want to regenerate the link each time a different radio button is pressed then you need to move it inside the `getResults` function. Otherwise it will be generated with the current initial value of `testVar` which is an empty string

Comment: Question tagged [tag:jquery].  Where is the jQuery?  Edited tags.

Comment: I placed it in the getResults function after the 'for' loop and that doesn't do it.

Comment: @user1511039, see the live example in my answer. Is that what all of us think you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>**[SEE LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MGud5/)**</kbd>

Following on my comment, you can do a couple of changes.

1. The `id` attributes should be unique. You can use a classname instead of using an `id`.

   ```
   <form>
       <label>Priority 1</label>
       <input type="radio" class="priority" name="priorityN" onclick="getResults();" value="prior1" />
       <label>Priority 2</label>
       <input type="radio" class="priority" name="priorityN" onclick="getResults();" value="prior2" />
   </form>
   ```
2. If you want to regenerate the link each time a different radio button is pressed then you need to move it inside the `getResults` function. Otherwise it will be generated with the current initial value of `testVar` which is an empty string.

   ```
   function getResults() {
       var testVar;
       var radios = document.getElementsByName("priorityN");
       for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
           if (radios[i].checked) {
               testVar = (radios[i].value);
               document.getElementById("myLink").innerHTML = '<a href=\"' + 'www.example.com?pri=' + testVar + '\" onclick=\"$(this).modal({width:880, height:460}).open(); return false;\" >' + 'My Modal Link' + "</a>";
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Alexander, great fix and the only problem is I want there to be a link shown before a radio button is selected. Instead of a text link I will use a button labeled "Edit Selected". Need the button to show prior to a radio button clicked???

Comment: @user1511039, just add the button HTML inside the `myLink` div element as any other

Comment: Figured it out. I will place an image in the <div> and it will disappear and the linked image will appear when a radio button is clicked. Great demo Alexander and thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I modern browsers you can use `querySelector` and forget about loops:

```
function getResults() {
  var checked = document.querySelector('[name="priorityN"]:checked'),
      link = document.querySelector('#myLink');
  link.innerHTML = '<a href="...'+ checked.value +'">...</a>';
}
```